# How the Dirac spinor change under the Lorentz transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, inertial-frames, dirac-equation, spinors

My question is, what form do Dirac spinors take under Lorentz transformations?
I would be grateful if you could send me the answer this year

Comment: [Lorentz transformation of Dirac spinor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528866/lorentz-transformation-of-dirac-spinor)